# Office addin deploy to all users

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, netoffice

Actually i create an addin to office with NetOffice. This work well. I create a setup project in VStudio 2010. When I install my addin to current user only this work well but not when I install to All users.

In my setup project in User/Machine hive of Registry view, il set all necessary registry keys.

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to 64-bit installations.

When the app is installed for All users on 64-bit Windows, registry keys from User/Machine Hive are placed in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Wow6432Node.

When it's installed for Current user or on 32-bit Windows, the keys are correctly placed into HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Office...